# Vim: If editing line in window bottom, also show next 4-5 lines

Tags: vim

Don't exactly know what to search for:
If i edit text in vim it sometimes happen that i edit the last visible line. I'd like also to see the next 5 lines, so i'm looking for something like an "edit margin". Or something like: If i edit the third last line vim should scroll down 2 lines automatic. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the `scrolloff` option.

```
:set scrolloff=5
```

This keeps 5 lines visible above/below the cursor.

Comment: This is apparently the default in Ubuntu 18.04, or at least Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL. I thought I was running into a weird bug but thanks to you I found that it's just a setting and managed to restore the old behaviour. So thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `set scrolloff=5'.